# I want to display a birthday count of people as how many other people who have the birthday in same month via trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, community

I want to display the birthday count field as a result just besides the DOB field as the how many other contacts have the birthday in the same month excluding that contact whenever any new record added or updated. 
The result should be like below:
Expected result (table)

Contact DOB        Result
Alex - 01.01.1960 - 2
Matt - 01.03.1997 - 0
Jane - 21.01.1986 - 2
Adam - 15.02.1977 - 1
Hannah - 30.01.2001 - 2
Monica - 14.02.1966 - 1

I have already wriiten code for insert contact via trigger so, it correctly displays the birthday count for new record and it also do changes in existing records result field after adding new record and code for that is as below:

```
public static void BeforeInsert(List<Contact__c> c)
{
    Integer DOB_Month_Count = 0;

    for(Contact__c c2 :c)
    {
        c2.Birthday_Count__c =DOB_Month_Count;
    }


    for(Contact__c c1: [select Date_of_Birth__c from Contact__c])
    {
        for(Contact__c c2:c)
        {
            Integer DOB_month_existing = c1.Date_of_Birth__c.month();

            Integer DOB_month_requsted = c2.Date_of_Birth__c.month();
            if(DOB_month_existing == DOB_month_requsted)
            {

                system.debug(DOB_month_existing);  
                DOB_Month_Count = DOB_Month_Count + 1;
                c2.Birthday_Count__c = DOB_Month_Count;
                c1.Birthday_Count__c = DOB_Month_Count;
                update c1;
                //insert c2;
            }
        }
    }
    for(Contact__c c1: [select Date_of_Birth__c from Contact__c])
    {
        for(Contact__c c2:c)
        {
            Integer DOB_month_existing = c1.Date_of_Birth__c.month();

            Integer DOB_month_requsted = c2.Date_of_Birth__c.month();
            if(DOB_month_existing == DOB_month_requsted)
            {
                c1.Birthday_Count__c = c2.Birthday_Count__c;
                update c1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I update the record it also changes the result field for that record with correct value. However, the problem is it's not changing the other relevant contacts result with that update which has birthday in the same month. The code is below

```
public static void Beforeupdate(List<Contact__c> c)
{
    Integer DOB_Month_Count = 0;

    for(Contact__c c2 :c)
    {
        c2.Birthday_Count__c = DOB_Month_Count;
    }  


    for(Contact__c c1: [select Date_of_Birth__c from Contact__c])
    {
        for(Contact__c c2 :c)
        {
            Integer DOB_month_existing = c1.Date_of_Birth__c.month();

            Integer DOB_month_requsted = c2.Date_of_Birth__c.month();
            if(DOB_month_existing == DOB_month_requsted)
            {   

                system.debug(DOB_month_existing);  
                DOB_Month_Count = DOB_Month_Count + 1;
                c2.Birthday_Count__c = DOB_Month_Count;
                //c1.Birthday_Count__c =DOB_Month_Count;
                // update c1;
                //insert c2;
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void Afterupdate(List<Contact__c> c)
{
    Integer count = 0;
    Set<Id> conID = new Set<Id> (); 
    for(Contact__c con: c)
    { 
        if(con.Id != Null)
        { 
            conID.add (con.Id); 
        } 
    } 
    List<Contact__c> lstContact = new List<Contact__c>();
    for(Contact__c c2 :c)
    {
        for(Contact__c c3 : [select Date_of_Birth__c from Contact__cc])
        {
            Integer DOB_month_existing = c3.Date_of_Birth__c.month();

            Integer DOB_month_requsted = c2.Date_of_Birth__c.month();
            if(DOB_month_existing == DOB_month_requsted)
            {
                c3.Birthday_Count__c = c2.Birthday_Count__c;
                update c3;
            }
            if(c3.Id == c2.Id)
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            lstContact.add(c3);
        }
    }
    update lstContact;
}
}
```

Please help me to resolve this any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a coding service, so questions that sound like "do my work for me" tend to be received poorly. The goal of this site is to help make you a better programmer or admin by helping you overcome specific issues. If you've already tried writing some code for this, including that code here and pointing to a very specific part that you're having trouble with helps make questions better received (and tend to make the answers you receive more accurate). You should add information to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: can anybody explain what is the pattern/use case for output?

Comment: I have explained things in best way I can do. Earlier, I don't know but why my description of the problem deleted automatically. Otherwise, I have mentioned every details as much as I can do and @Darek I requested help to solve this so, please it's my request to help me if it's possible I have no intention to tell people do my work for me as I have already done 70-80% work it's just that I am having an issue with only in one section.

Comment: The current implementation is not workable with any significant data volume because it's not bulkified and it attempts to query and process the entire Contact table multiple times. I'd strongly recommend you try an approach built around [Aggregate Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm), or change your data model so that you do not have to place counts on each contact. A lookup to a Birthday object should do nicely.

Comment: I've gone and edited your code so that the formatting is consistent (indentation, spaces between operators, bracket style, removed some completely blank lines). Being consistent, especially in indentation, is very important for making it easier for other people to read and understand your code. I've also retracted my close vote.

Comment: Thank you @DerekF it's a great help. I would keep in mind that :)

Comment: @DavidReed Can you elaborate more in deatils and any suggestions in details for changing my data models. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the big problem with this approach in a nutshell:

```
for(Contact__c c1: [select Date_of_Birth__c from Contact__c])
{
    for(Contact__c c2:c)
    {
        // code snipped for brevity
        update c1;
    }
}
```

You do this or something like this three times, and it contains three disastrous issues.

1. It queries the entire `Contact__c` table without filters.

   Even in orgs where this succeeds, the performance will be terrible, and trying to iterate that many records (more than once!) places you at risk of the CPU time limit. In many orgs, it will not succeed. The SOQL limit is 50,000 rows, but even if you used a `LIMIT` clause you'd get a selectivity exception in an org with enough data volume (200,000 total records).
2. It performs a combinatoric search. It iterates over two lists of Contacts inside one another and compares every record to every other record. This has a complexity proportional to `N * M`, where your org has `N` total Contacts and `M` Contacts are being processed by the trigger. The limit risk here is also CPU time.
3. It performs DML not just in a loop but in a *nested* loop. This fails the basic principle of bulkification and will result in a `LimitException` once the total number of DML statements executed reaches 150. When you're running an update for every Contact that shares a birthday with any other Contact, *for every other Contact that has the same birthday*, that 150 DML statements will evaporate *really* fast.

I will quickly sketch three alternate approaches and encourage you to explore them further through Trailhead or the Salesforce documentation. In particular, you should consider completing the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit to understand bulkification patterns.

## Approach 1: Aggregate Queries

If you insist on maintaining the "Same Birthday Count" on every Contact in real time using triggers (which I think is a bad idea), the way to do it is with [SOQL Aggregate Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm). The skeleton of this solution would look like this, for your Insert case:

```
Set<Date> newBirthdates;

// Add all of the Birthdates of new Contacts to the set.

// Use an Aggregate Query to get the count of existing Contacts with the same birthdates.
List<AggregateResult> birthdayCounts = [
    SELECT count(Id), Date_of_Birth__c
    FROM Contact__c
    WHERE Date_of_Birth__c IN :newBirthdates
    GROUP BY Date_of_Birth__c
];

// Process the Aggregate Results into a Map<Date, Integer>, where the key is the birthdate and the value is the count.
Map<Date, Integer> birthdayCountMap = new Map<Date, Integer>();

// Then loop over the new Contacts again and update their counts, adding one for the new record.
for (Contact__c c1 : c) {
    if (c1.Date_of_Birth__c != null) {
        c1.Birthday_Count__c = birthdayCountMap.get(c1.Date_of_Birth__c) + 1;
    }
}

// Then, query for all Contacts that have the same birthdays, and update them.
// Note that we only process those Contacts that we have to!
List<Contact> existingContacts = [SELECT Id, Date_of_Birth__c FROM Contact WHERE Date_of_Birth__c IN :newBirthdates];
for (Contact__c c1 : existingContacts) {
    c1.Birthday_Count__c = birthdayCountMap.get(c1.Date_of_Birth__c) + 1;
}
// Update the Contacts. Note exactly one DML operation is performed, on the List.
update existingContacts;
```

The Update case would have a little more complex logic but the same type of operations would be performed. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

## Approach 2: Lookup to Birthday Object

Instead of using code to maintain a birthday count, create a new `Birthday__c` object, and insert 366 of them (one per day of the year). Have your trigger populate or update a lookup from `Contact__c` to `Birthday__c`, based on the `Date_of_Birth__c` field.

Then, use a tool like [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to roll up the count of Contacts to a field on the `Birthday__c` object. You can then surface that count on the Contact itself via a formula field through the lookup to the Birthday object.

You run the risk of data skew-related with a solution like this in a large data volume org. If you are working on such an org, you should be receiving guidance from an architect or tech lead.

## Approach 3: UI Only

If you don't need the data for reporting or automation, consider just displaying it to the user via a Visualforce page or Lightning component that you place within the page layout or in the Lightning Record Page assigned to the Contact.

That display component can perform a simpler, less costly query, along the lines of

```
SELECT count() FROM Contact__c WHERE Date_of_Birth__c = :thisContact.Date_of_Birth__c
```

and show the user that information only. No triggers and no DML is required, and you do not incur the overhead of maintaining this information across every record in your org.